# restore.dg is not fitlered by .gitignore

Tags: github, asp.net-core, gitignore

In my newest .NET Core ASP.MVC project I seem to be unable to ignore the restore.dg file. By default, the Visual Studio .gitignore file is set to ignore the whole .vs/ folder, in which the file is located. As this did not work, I tried several methods how to get rid of the file, yet unsuccessfully.

```
# Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/
restore.dg
*.dg
.vs/*
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove it from the cache.

```
git rm --cached .vs/restore.dg
git commit -m "Remove restore.dg from the cache"
```

See also: [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/1108891)

Answer (score 1):

This might happen after you have already committed this file into the repository. If this is the case you have to remove it using `git rm --cached <filename>` command and commit this change to the repository. After that it will disappear from `git status` and will never bother you again.

Comment: `git rm <filename>` will delete the file locally, which isn't what the original poster wants. The original poster just wants to remove it from the repo.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin, you are right, I have updated my answer.